# golang define variable with newline

Tags: go

How do you define variable value that includes new line?

```
const statement = "SELECT *
                   FROM `users` u;";
```

[image]

It shows error `newline in string`.

Comment: For future questions, [don't paste images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would normally use a raw string literal like this

```
const s = `first line
second line`
```

However, this is not possible in your case since the string itself contains backticks. In this case I would use `+` to connect the lines:

```
const statement = "SELECT *" +
                  " FROM `users` u;";
```

The string value in this example does not contain a newline (but that's ok for SQL). If you really want a newline in the string, use the escape sequence `\n`.

```
const s = "first line\nsecond line"
```

Comment: It’s also OK to remove the backticks from the SQL, since “users” is not a reserved word in any flavour of SQL. MySQL unfortunately dumps schema with every entity name backtick wrapped, whether it needs it or not.